# Use of AND operator in Jython

Tags: jython

I am trying to use AND operator in Jython

> If a!=b AND a!=C :

Can we not do that ,because i am getting syntax error?

> SyntaxError: mismatched input 'AND' expecting COLON

Help?

Answer (score 0):

If only i had little patience!!
It was just uppercase AND creating issue #grin

> if a!=b and a!=c:

Works great!